# How to draw four points which are detected by contours using opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I need to know how do i draw lines between four points? all points are detected by contours. 
There are four red points.as shown below  these points are detected using cv2.findContours. After I need to draw lines on each of points like a rectangle. Can someone please help me to solve this ? Also I used convexhull to do this but i couldn't sort it out.

[image]

here is the code that i used

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
RedMask = cv2.inRange(hsv,(0,100,100),(10,255,255))
contours1, _ = cv2.findContours(RedMask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
for cnt1 in contours1: 
   #area = cv2.contourArea(cnt1) 
   #Draw it 
   #cv2.drawContours(frame,[cnt],0,(255,0,0),2)

   hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt1)
   cv2.drawContours(frame,hull,3,(255,0,0),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#cv2.drawContours), you can use it in the following way.

```
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, index, color, thickness)
```

If you pass `index=-1`, it will draw all the contours. If you pass `index=3`, it will draw the fourth contour in the array of contours. In this, if your convexHull array consist of only one contour, you can pass `index=-1`

Comment: I went that way before.it didn't work. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try cv2.polylines:

```
#first we need to change the shape of the array
(count,_,_) = hull.shape
hull.ravel()
hull.shape = (count,2)

#some blank img to drow on
blank = np.zeros_like(frame)

#drawing
cv2.polylines(blank,np.int32([hull]),True,255)
```

Note that we need to convert data type of the array (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241830/opencv-polylines-function-in-python-throws-exception))